# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'setCollisionByExclusion' of null

Tags: javascript, json, game-engine

So I'm trying to write a game not knowing any JS using Phaser 3

The code is

```
var map;
var player;
var cursors;
var groundLayer, coinLayer;
var text;
var score = 0;

function preload() {
    this.load.tilemapTiledJSON('map', 'assets/test.json');
    this.load.spritesheet('tiles', 'assets/tiles.png', {frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 32});
    this.load.atlas('player', 'assets/postac.png', 'assets/postac.json');
}

function create() {
    map = this.make.tilemap({key: 'map'});

    var groundTiles = map.addTilesetImage('tiles');
    groundLayer = map.createDynamicLayer('World', groundTiles, 0, 0);
    groundLayer.setCollisionByExclusion([1]);

    // set the boundaries of our game world
    this.physics.world.bounds.width = groundLayer.width;
    this.physics.world.bounds.height = groundLayer.height;

    // create the player sprite
    player = this.physics.add.sprite(200, 200, 'player');
    player.setBounce(0.2); // our player will bounce from items
    player.setCollideWorldBounds(true); // don't go out of the map

    this.physics.add.collider(groundLayer, player);
```

basically it's copy-pasted

and also if that could help

I'm getting "Invalid Tilemap Layer ID: World" warning

I tried changing -1 to 1 but that didn't help

Comment: It means that `groundLayer` in `groundLayer.setCollisionByExclusion([1])` is `null`. The error you mention suggests this is because  the `map.createDynamicLayer('World', groundTiles, 0, 0)` fails.

Comment: Indention decreased